# Sort string by Shell Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, shell, sorting

I have a text file of 50 string lines of varying length and content. I need to read the file and sort in ascending order. 
Sorting condition: the number of words in a sentence that start from the letter "a"

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String token1 = "";
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("E:\\text.txt"));

    List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();
    inFile1.useDelimiter(". ");

    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
        token1 = inFile1.nextLine();
        temps.add(token1);
    }
    inFile1.close();

    String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < tempsArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(tempsArray[i]);
    }

    int cnt = 0; //counts of words in the string line
    for (int i=0; i<tempsArray.length; i++) {
        int k=0; //counts of words that start from the letter "а"
        System.out.println("Line № = " + i);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tempsArray[i]);           
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            cnt++;
            String s= st.nextToken();
            if (s.charAt(0)=='a') {                    
                k++;               
            }             
        }
       System.out.println("Words count = " + cnt);
       cnt=0;
       System.out.println("Words 'а' = " + k);  
    }       
}
```

New question: how do i move to sorting string lines by **k** ? What else should I do after that code?

Comment: Why not give it a try first, and see how far you can get, based on what you know about different Data Types in Java? Then if you get stuck, post a question.

Comment: I don't need help with coding. I need help with making algorithm of this task. Then i'll try to write code for that algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this code](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/Shell.java.html) for shell sort, it will work with both numbers and strings. First you need to store all strings in the array.

In the reference that I gave, you should change the main method with a code like the following one, to read input from your file and store in an array.

```
 String token1 = "";

// create Scanner inFile1
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("YourFilenNme"));

List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();


while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
  // find next line
  token1 = inFile1.next();
  temps.add(token1);
}
inFile1.close();

String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

Shell.sort(tempsArray);
    show(tempsArray);
```

Edit:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     String s= st.nextToken();
     if (s.charAt(0)=='a')
     {
         "do what you want here"
     }

 }
```

Comment: In the code that I wrote, it stores each line as a array item. After edit section, I showed how you can tokenize the string and how to check if the first char is 'a'.